# Possible to have two different sets of information for every other page?

Tags: xetex, packages, books

I am aware of `\paracol` and do love it, but I am curious, is there any way to do something similar but with whole pages? I am using the `\book` class specifically.

Like say I wanted mirror, for whatever reason, the same exact information, but in two different languages. For me, I am trying to deal with translating a public domain Russian document, which is not a strong language of mine, and so I wanted to reproduce it with the original Russian on the left and my translation on the right, in case I get anything wrong, it will make correcting it easier in the future.

Sure, I could just use page breaks,but that would become altogether too difficult, and I would prefer to keep one language per `\subfile`.

If there is no feature, I shall simply just use `\paracol`, but hey.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the `reledpar` package can do this.

Comment: @DavidPurton Thank you! I am checking this out now!

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar a couple of times. As you can see, the paragraphs are nicely placed so that what belongs together stays together.

This is how an approach using pdflatex would look like:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{paratype}

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\date{\today}
\title{War and Peace - \selectlanguage{russian}“Война и мир”}
\author{Leo Tolstoy}
\maketitle

\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                \begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
                     -- Еh bien, mon prince. Genes et Lucques ne sont plus que des apanages, des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous previens, que si vous ne me dites pas, que nous avons la guerre, si vous vous permettez encore de pallier toutes les infamies, toutes les atrocites de cet Antichrist (ma parole, j'y crois) -- je ne vous connais plus, vous n'etes plus mon ami, vous n'etes plus мой верный раб, comme vous dites. Ну, здравствуйте, здравствуйте. Je vois que je vous fais peur, садитесь и рассказывайте.
                \end{otherlanguage}
            \pend
            \pstart
                \begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
                    Так говорила в июле 1805 года известная Анна Павловна Шерер, фрейлина и приближенная императрицы Марии Феодоровны, встречая важного и чиновного князя Василия, первого приехавшего на ее вечер. Анна Павловна кашляла несколько дней, у нее был грипп, как она говорила (грипп был тогда новое слово, употреблявшееся только редкими).
                \end{otherlanguage}
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                    “Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don't tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist--I really believe he is Antichrist--I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my 'faithful slave,' as you call yourself! But how do you do? I see I have frightened you--sit down and tell me all the news.”
            \pend
            \pstart
                    It was in July, 1805, and the speaker was the well-known Anna Pavlovna Scherer, maid of honor and favorite of the Empress Marya Fedorovna. With these words she greeted Prince Vasili Kuragin, a man of high rank and importance, who was the first to arrive at her reception. Anna Pavlovna had had a cough for some days. She was, as she said, suffering from la grippe; grippe being then a new word in
St. Petersburg, used only by the elite.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 

\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image: Russian-English translation]